# custom membership 3 part login

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, universal-provider

Looking to implement a custom a DefaultMembershipProvider using the universal providers, this provider needs to handle 3 segments for authentication.

1. GroupID
2. UserName
3. Password

At present I have functions which pass back into the default code by joining together the GroupID and the Username as a username like below

```
 public UserMembership GetUser(int GroupID, string username, bool userIsOnline)
{
    UserMembership user = new UserMembership(base.GetUser(GroupID.ToString() + ":" + username, userIsOnline));

    return user;
}
```

To me this just feels like a hack, a clean hack but still a hack. Anyone got any better idea's how to implement this without pretty much writing a full provider from scratch.

Comment: Couldn't you simply use the default provider and use Roles for the group id?

Comment: unfortunately I'm actually using the roles